# Redirecting anything in a subdirectory to an absolute directory path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Using a RewriteRule I'm trying to redirect every url in a subdirectory to another subdirectory as an absolute path, trimming anything that came after the first directory.  Example:

www.domain.com/store/search
www.domain.com/store/search?search=some_term

etc.

all need to go to

www.domain.com/newdir/

unfortunately the results I am seeing are like such:

www.domain.com/store/newdir/
www.domain.com/store/newdir/?search=some_term

and so on.  I am using this command currently:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule search(.*) newdir/ [R=301,NC,L]

How can I redirect anything in /store/search to just simply /newdir, trimming anything that comes after the word "search"?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .htaccess is in the root directory you can do something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^store/search(.*)?$ ./newdir/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Or if the .htaccess is in the "store" directory you could do this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search(.*)?$ http://www.domain.com/newdir/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

The above is to keep the query strings, if you want to just redirect to the directory remove the $1

Comment: Thank you sdexp.  I have an .htaccess in both directories actually, root and "store".  I put your suggestions in both and unfortunately still getting a result that includes the query despite removing the $1:

http://www.domain.com/store/newdir/?search=some_term

Maybe I made an error. Here are the rules I added:<br>

**Store Dir .htaccess:**<br>
RewriteRule ^search(.*)?$ http://www.domain.com/newdir/ [R=301,NC,L]
**Root Dir .htaccess:**
RewriteRule ^store/search(.*)?$ ./newdir/ [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: Try changing it to `RewriteRule ^store/search(.*)?$ http://www\.domain\.com/newdir/ [NC,L,R=301]`. Also, sometimes I'd say if you have a rule set up it can stay in your browser's cache so my advice would be to clear cache, re-open your browser or try a different browser to double-check if the redirect is in your cache or not.

Comment: And don't have a duplicate rule in two directories. Choose one and delete the rule from the other .htaccess

Comment: Hi sdexp, I think we're getting closer. The rule you suggested gets me to the right landing page.  The query is still remaining, but the landing page ignores it.  I kept this in the /store/ directory _RewriteRule ^search(.*)?$ http://www.domain.com/newdir/ [NC,L,R=301]_ and the url example is being redirected to _http://www.domain.com/newdir/?search=some_term
_.  As a side note, _www.domain.com/store/search_ with no query works perfectly.

The query is ignored, so it is working, just wish I could remove the query.  Thanks!

Comment: @micah-sharp `RewriteRule ^search(.*)?$ /newdir/ [NC,L,R=301]` should not keep the query string in the URL. Only if the `$1` is there should the query string be there. Did you clear cache or try a different browser?

Comment: Also, double check you don't have another .htaccess somewhere else that might have a conflicting rule in it.

Comment: Hi sdexp, yes, I used a different browser and incognito/private window.  For some reason the query remains, but as I mentioned it works as I had hoped.  Very weird, I'll look for conflicting rules.  Thx